# How to highlight pinned tab in Chromium via javascript

Tags: javascript, api, chromium

There is a feature in Chrome - you can right-click on a tab and select "Pin Tab", then tab is moved to the left corner and looks like an icon with text.

So there is the question: how can I highlight this tab? Maybe there is some API?

For example, gmail can highlight this tab when new mail message is come.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can't blink the tab, just the tab title:

```
<script>
function blinkTitle() {
 if(!window.oldtitle) window.oldtitle = document.title;
 if(document.title == ' ') {
  document.title = window.oldtitle;
 } else {
  document.title = ' ';
 }
}
function startBlink() {
 window.blinkinterval = setInterval(blinkTitle,200);
}
onload = function() {
 document.onblur = function() {
  setTimeout(startBlink,2000);
 }
 document.onfocus = function() {
  clearInterval(window.blinkinterval);
  document.title = window.oldtitle;
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: tis not what I want. Just pin the tab with gmail in Chromium on Windows 7 and wait for a new mail - then you will see what I want :)

Comment: @silent: I tried it myself, and it does exactly the same thing. Y'know what? I'll post some code below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an HTML page that changes the page's title after 10 seconds:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function blinkPinnedTab()
         {
            var title = document.title;
            var newTitle = "New Message";

            window.setTimeout(function()
            { 
               document.title = newTitle;
               window.setTimeout(function()
               { 
                  document.title = oldTitle;
               }, 1000);
            }, 1);
         }

         window.setTimeout(function() { blinkPinnedTab(); }, 10000);
      </script>
      <title>Yo, Yo!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      Hello!
   </body>
</html>
```

To see the "highlight animation" do the following:

1. Load the page.
2. Pin the tab.
3. Switch to a different tab. (Because if the tab is the active tab, nothing will happen.)
4. Within 10 seconds of loading the page, the tab will be "highlighted".

You have to do steps 2-3 within 10 seconds to see the effect. If you didn't, then just reload the page and quickly switch to a different tab.

EDIT: I still think that charles.art.br's answer is just as good (actually, it's better). There's very little difference between the code samples we both gave. I honestly don't know why his answer wasn't accepted.